# I wan to print my text into the <div> tag, but it doesn't print

Tags: javascript, html, xml, toggle

This is my Ajax Function

```
function xhttp() {
      // Create an XMLHttpRequest object
      const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var hourArray;
      // Define a callback function
      xhttp.onload = function () {
        var parser, xmlDoc;
        var text = this.responseText;
        parser = new DOMParser();
        xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/xml");
        hourArray = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");
        booking_hours(hourArray);
      };
      // Send a request
      xhttp.open("GET", "test.xml");
      xhttp.send();
        }
```

When any is clicked ajax function will work

```
dataCel.on("click", function () {
  var thisEl = $(this);
  var thisDay = $(this).attr("data-day").slice(8);
  var thisMonth = $(this).attr("data-day").slice(5, 7);

  $(".c-aside__num").text(thisDay);
  $(".c-aside__month").text(monthText[thisMonth - 1]);
  $(".c-aside__year").text(dateObj.getUTCFullYear() + indexYear);
  xhttp();

  dataCel.removeClass("isSelected");
  thisEl.addClass("isSelected");
});
```

When ajax will work I want to read  hours to my text and print this text into div tag

```
  function booking_hours(hourArray) {
    var table;
    for (var i = 0; i < hourArray.length; i++) {
      if (parseInt(hourArray[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue) < 9)
        table +=
          "<div data-hours='0" +
          hourArray[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
          ".00-0" +
          (parseInt(hourArray[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue) + 1) +
          ".00' class='hour_cell'>" +
          "<p>" +
          "0" +
          hourArray[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
          ".00 - 0" +
          (parseInt(hourArray[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue) + 1) +
          ".00" +
          "</p></div>";
      else if (parseInt(hourArray[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue) == 9) {
        table +=
          "<div data-hours='0" +
          hourArray[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
          ".00-0" +
          (parseInt(hourArray[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue) + 1) +
          ".00' class='hour_cell'>" +
          "<p>" +
          "0" +
          hourArray[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
          ".00 - " +
          (parseInt(hourArray[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue) + 1) +
          ".00" +
          "</p></div>";
      } else {
        table +=
          "<div data-hours='" +
          hourArray[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
          ".00-" +
          (parseInt(hourArray[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue) + 1) +
          ".00' class='hour_cell'>" +
          "<p>" +
          hourArray[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
          ".00 - " +
          (parseInt(hourArray[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue) + 1) +
          ".00" +
          "</p></div>";
      }
    }
    console.log(table.slice(9));
    document.getElementsById("hoursList").innerHTML = table.slice(9);
  }
```

This console log print this         console.log(table.slice(9));

```
<div data-hours='02.00-03.00' class='hour_cell'><p>02.00 - 03.00</p></div><div data-hours='08.00-09.00' class='hour_cell'><p>08.00 - 09.00</p></div><div data-hours='10.00-11.00' class='hour_cell'><p>10.00 - 11.00</p></div><div data-hours='16.00-17.00' class='hour_cell'><p>16.00 - 17.00</p></div>
```

But this innerHTML doesn't print what console log printed

```
 document.getElementsById("hoursList").innerHTML = table.slice(9);
```

Div tag that I want to use.

```
<div id="hoursList" class="hours__list"></div>
```

Comment: That's because `document.getElementsById` doesn't exist. Open your console, it's telling you `Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsById is not a function`.

Comment: Also, instead of all the old `new XMLHttpRequest(), xhttp.onload,  xhttp.open, xhttp.get` literature, you should just use the more modern [fetch](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-fetch-api/) ;)

Comment: Ok thanks,now I am learning :). This is my school project. Thanks for your helping, I solved this shameful problem :D. How did i not see this !